# Show action bar also for menu button?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm creating an action bar on ICS. Due to spacing only the icons are displayed.
But I'd also like to supply the action bar as context-like menu *with* text if the menu button of the phone is pressed.

How can I achieve this?

Atm I have 3 icons. 2 of them are displayed at the top in action bar.
If I press the menu phone button, the 3rd is displayed as contextmenu! But I'd like to have all 3 of them.

```
class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();

        /* IMPLEMENTATION HERE */
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile... where is the `return` statement?

Comment: `//inflace etc` should indicate that there is more to come, of course also a return statement. The question is not really about the code, but about how to achieve that both action bar and context menu button can display all of the menu items?

Comment: Do you mean the **overflow** menu? A context menu offers actions that affect a specific item or context frame in the UI. They are used for a different purpose than the Action Bar.

Comment: Oh ok, then I misused the term "context menu". I mean the *old* options menu that was present in eg GINGERBREAD: if the user presses the phones' menu button, he can choose: Options, About, Impressum, etc. My problem now is, that I would like to have both: the ICS ActionBar and the old menu popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [**Menus**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html):

> If a menu item does not appear as an action item, then the system places it in the overflow menu.

Thus, showing the same action item in both the action bar *and* the overflow menu is not possible. What you *could* do is this:

1. Check (at runtime) which menu items fit in the Action Bar and which do not.
2. For each menu item that is displayed in the Action Bar, create a new, identical menu item dynamically, making sure to call `newMenuItem.setShowAsAction(SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)` to ensure that it is displayed in the overflow menu (w/ text).

This, in my opinion, goes against Android's menu design standards and I wouldn't suggest doing it. It might appear like a better design choice in your eyes, but users expect apps to be consistent across the entire Android platform. Manipulating your menus in weird ways can cause confusion, and can negatively impact user experience as a result.

Comment: Ok thanks for this. I think I will follow your suggestion and leave it the way it is.